# Allocate a sum on entries in a database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have the following situation:
My table has entries with a structure like this:

```
Name      Section  Capacity
Name1        A       10
Name2        B       20
Name3        A       15
Name2        C       30
```

And then i have a specific number i want to allocate on the different entries based on the number and beginning from section A to C. 
So when i want to allocate 30 I want to beginn with Name1 -10, Name3 -15 and Name2 -5. 
Is this possible somehow in sql? or do i have to even write a macro in access for this task?

Thanks
Ralph

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  If you want things in a particular order, you need a column that specifies that ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - It looks like it's ordered on Section ASC, Name ASC.  The question is, can you then subtract a number from the running sum of Capacity?  And, in this case, you'd have a remainder of 5 left over after you zero out both Section A's, so you would only subtract *part* of the Section B record.

Comment: It needs a bit of VBA and play with Recordset Looping. Not a simple Query that can fix this. That's my VHO.

Comment: thanks guys. :)
I think in vba it's not that hard. just wanted to know if its possible just in sql.